# Google Apps Script getSheetByName returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Results from `getSheetName` and `getSheetByName` are strange

```
    function BE1() {
  console.log("BE1() triggered");
  var variables = globalVariables(); //load the Global variables 
  console.log("sheetid = ", variables.sheetid);
  var sheetName = 'BE1';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetid)
  if (!ss) {
    console.log("spreadsheet not found");
  }  else  {
    var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets();
    console.log("spreadsheet has ", numSheets, " sheets");
    var someSheet = ss.getSheetName();
    console.log("someSheet = ", someSheet);
    if (sheetName === someSheet) {
      console.log("names match");
    }  else  {
      console.log("names do not match");
    }  
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) {
      console.log("sheet BE1 not found");
    }  else  {
      console.log("sheet = ", sheet);
      var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
      console.log("lastrow = ", lastrow);
      console.log("question column = ", variables.question);
      var nextQuestion = sheet.getRange(lastrow, variables.question).getValue(nextQuestion);
      SlidesApp.getUi().alert(nextQuestion);
    }
  }
```

The console log:

```
> Stackdriver logs
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   BE1() triggered
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   sheetid =  1QiuqmfF1z4Fe_RVD5BmPhvxq5sloHZs8ANFQ8gRLabA
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   spreadsheet has  2  sheets
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   someSheet =  BE1
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   names match
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   sheet =  {}
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   lastrow =  2
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Debug   question column =  1
Oct 12, 2020, 2:40:11 PM    Error   Exception: The parameters (null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue.
    at BE1(Code:45:70)
```

Note the string matches whatever sheet is retrieved by `ss.getSheetName()` but does not work with `getSheetByName`. What stupid error am I making? I have broken all the code down to separate lines in order to display to console.

Comment: Notice that the error says " The parameters(null)" and not "Cannot find  method getRange() of null". The latter says `sheet` is  null(when used as `sheet.getRange()`), while the former says the argument passed ( parameter) is null. It doesn't say sheet is null.

Comment: I upvote the question because the OP tried to console.log every part of the code he/she thought may have caused the error. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

**Replace**:

`var nextQuestion = sheet.getRange(lastrow, variables.question).getValue(nextQuestion);`

**with**

`var nextQuestion = sheet.getRange(lastrow, variables.question).getValue();`.

---

### Issues:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) **does not** accept any arguments.

---

- Also `nextQuestion` is not defined in the code snippet you shared;
  before it is used. Therefore, `nextQuestion` is **null** and this is
  why you get:

  > The parameters (**null**) don't match the method signature for
  > SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue.

---

### Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var someSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var nextQuestion;
someSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue(nextQuestion);
}
```

`nextQuestion` **does not** have a value.

This will give you the same error:

> The parameters (**null**) don't match the method signature for
> SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValue.

---

### Bonus Information:

`getSheetName()` is supposed to be used with a [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object and not with a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) object.

Therefore, instead of using:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(variables.sheetid)
var someSheet = ss.getSheetName();
```

it is **preferable** to use this logic instead:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var someSheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
```

if you want to get the **active** (selected) sheet.